# Set Videojs player dimensions so that It is responsive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video.js

I have a react application which uses VideoJS player. Currently to set the height and width of the player, I assign height and width value like this

```
assign(props, {
    ref: 'video',
    controls: true,
    width: "960", height: "600"
});

return (
    <div>
        <video {... props}>
            <source src={this.props.src} type={this.props.type} id={this.props.id}/>
        </video>
    </div>)
```

and here is the code where I put my player component.

```
return (
    <div className={c.container}>
        <div className='video-section'>
            <div>
                <Player/>
            </div>
```

But setting height and width like this is not responsive. How can I assign height and width to the player for responsive behavior?

Comment: Do you have the ability to set width with %?

Comment: Good question.  I get an error when trying to set this to 100% since the type is a number and not a string.  I can't override this with anything.  It simply does not seem responsive, and I'm moving on to something else at this point.